# when i run "npm run dist_win", get a error: "node_modules" Not an internal or external command？

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

i use "node_modules/.bin/webpack" but get this error?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `node_modules/.bin/` and just use `webpack -p`, npm will append that folder to your `PATH` automatically. Also, as a side note, you should use `cross-env` so you can get rid of `dist_win` script:

```
{
  "script": {
    "dist": "cross-env WEBPACK_ENV=online webpack -p"
  }
}
```